# what is the pdf of the ratio of two random log-normal variables

Tags: random-variable, lognormal-distribution

Assume , are two independent log-normal random variables. What is the distribution of /(+)?

Comment: Because $X+Y$ is not lognormal, your title is a little confusing.  BTW, are you assuming $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed or not?

Answer (score 1):

It follows that
$$
W=\frac{X}{X+Y}=\frac1{1+e^{-(\ln X-\ln Y)}}.
$$
Since $\ln X - \ln Y$ is normally distributed, and $W$ is the inverse logit of $\ln X - \ln Y$, $W$ has a [logit-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution).